# Monty Hall Problem simulation - win lose rate doesn't seem to match the expected outcome

Tags: probability, statistics, python, monty-hall

I created a simulation in Python for:

A) A player who sticks with the chosen door
B) A player who switches door after hosts opens a door without a price.

For scenario A) I get 66% lose rate (33% win rate) which validates the paradox.

The puzzling part for me is when I run the simulation for scenario B), I keep getting a 55% loose rate (45% win rate). Yes, winning odds improve, but I thought I'd get a winning rate close to 66%. I am not sure if the simulation is wrong, or if it's correct.

Here is the code that simulates scenario B):

Created a Player class:

When creating a Player object, it randomly picks a door.
Switch parameter allows me to control the behaviour (between switching doors or not)

```
from random import randrange
class Player:
    def __init__(self, switch):
        self.door = randrange(3)
        self.switch = switch

    def switch_door(self, open_door):
        doors = range(3)
        if(self.switch == True):
            for door in doors:
                if(door != self.door) and (door != open_door):
                    self.door = door

    def get_door(self):
        return self.door
```

Created a class Host:
When creating a Host object, it randomly assigns the winning door (this is because the paradox uses the host's knowledge to open a loosing door)

```
from random import randrange
class Host:
    def __init__(self):
        self.door_prize = randrange(3)

    def open_door(self, player_door):
        doors = range(3)
        for door in doors:
            if (door != self.door_prize) and (door != player_door):
                return door

    def get_prize(self):
        return self.door_prize
```

Main script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from player import Player
from host import Host

def win_price(player_door, prize_door):
    if player_door == prize_door:
        return "win"
    else:
        return "loose"

rounds = 100000
results = []

for i in range(rounds):
    player = Player(True)
    host = Host()
    open_door = host.open_door(player.get_door())
    player.switch_door(open_door)
    results.append(win_price(player.get_door(), host.get_prize()))

outcome_labels = ["Loose", "Win"]

loose_count = 0
win_count = 0

for result in results:
    if result == 'loose':
        loose_count += 1
    if result == 'win':
        win_count += 1


results_count = [loose_count, win_count]
print(loose_count)
print(win_count)
plt.pie(results_count, labels=outcome_labels, autopct='%1d%%')

plt.show()
```

Is this simulation correct? I keep getting a 55%-45% loose-win ratio

Comment: What do you do when the play guesses correctly?  How does that figure into your odds?

Comment: Imagine prize in door one. Player chooses door two. Host opens door three. Go through your code for switch_door line by line.  for each door do loop.  Door 1: not open door and not self door.  So self.door = 1.  Door 2: not open door and *no longer* self.door so self.door = 2.  Door 3 is open door do nothing.  End result.... self.door = 2.  Again.  the switch.door routine didn't switch.

Comment: One way to check your implementation is to collect complete statistics on the win rates for each possible way this game can go. There are 9 starting configurations (player's door, prize door) and (in 6 of these starting cases) two choices for the host, so 15 cases altogether. You should end up with 12 cases each happening 1/18 of the time and 100% wins for the player, and 3 cases happening each 1/9 of the time with 0% wins.

Answer (score 2):

Error 1:

Switch door error:

You go through the doors one by one.  If the door isn't the open door and isn't the users current door the user switches.  But if the user switches to a lower door we will then continue to the users original door which is *no longer* the users door and the user will switch *back* to the original.

Of for instance.  If the user chooses door 2 and is shown door 3. The program will go through door 1, which not being the users current door nor the shown door, will be switch to the users door.  But then the program goes to door 2, and door to is *no longer* the users door nor the shown door.  So that gets switched *back* to the users door, and the end result is the users door is not switched.

Same thing if users chooses door 3.  The user will switch to a lower door and then switch back.

So the solution is to break to loop

Solution 1:

```
def switch_door(self, open_door):
    doors = range(3)
    if(self.switch == True):
        for door in doors:
            if(door != self.door) and (door != open_door):
                self.door = door
                return
```

Error 2: (Thanks to Joriki) for catching this

show door error.

If the player chooses the door with the prize then the host has two choices of doors to show.  In the actual monty hall problem the host will randomly choose which of the two to choose.  But in your program you have the host automatically.

Which doesn't change anything if the user does the hold or switch strategies.  But it gives more information.  If the player uses the strategy switch if the host shows you the higher of the two remaining doors--- the prize will *always* be in the lower door, and if the host shows the lower of the two remaining doors hold or switch it doesn't matter.

So you program has the folowing outcomes:

Prize is door 1, Player chooses door 1.  Outcome.  Host shows door two. Player switches to Door 3. LOSE (1-9 times) (This should actually be two 1-18 times options with host sometimes showing door three.)

Prize is door 1, Player chooses door 2. Outcome.  Host shows door three. Player switches to door 1, but switches back to door 2.  LOSE (1-9) times. (This should actually be a win.)

Prize is door 1, Player chooses door 3.  Outcome: Host shows door three.  Player switches to 1 and back to 3. LOSE (1-9)(This should actually be a win)

Prize is door 2, Player chooses door 1.  Outcome: Host shows door 3.  Player Switches to door 2.  WIN (1-9). (As it should be.)

Prize is door 2, Player chooses door 2. Host shows door 1. Player switches to door 3.  LOOSE (1-9)  (This should be two 1-18 occurances when host shows door 3.  If that had happened with the current swith_door program, player would have switched to door 1 and back to door 2 and win which he shouldn't.)

Prize is door 2, Player chooses door 3.  Host shows door 1. Player switches to door 2, and then back to door 3.  LOSE (1-9) (this should have been a win.)

Prize in door 3. Player chooses door 1.  Host shows door 2.  Player switches to door 3, WIN (1-9) (as it should be)

Prize in door 3. Player chooses door 2. Host shows door 1.  Player switches to door 3, WIN (1-9) (as it should be)

Prize in door 3, Player chooses door 3.  Host shows door 1.  Player switchest to 2 and then back to 3. WIN (should be a LOSE and also should be two 1-18 events).

So WIN = $\frac 49 = 44$ and LOSE = $\frac 59= 56$.

Comment: You're assuming that the door to be opened by the host is correctly chosen uniformly randomly from all doors that are not the player's chosen door or the prize door. In fact `open_door` returns the least such door without random choice.

Comment: I knew I was missing something, the result did not match what I was expecting. Thank you for taking the time to help a python newby.

Comment: After adding the missing return, it works as expected. @fleablood you nailed it!

Comment: "You're assuming that the door to be opened by the host is correctly chosen uniformly randomly from all doors that are not the player's chosen door or the prize door. In fact open_door returns the least such door without random choice."  Ah thats a second error.  That would eliminate a win.